# how to enumerate all the well-known SID's of a system via Windows API?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, sid

Is there a Windows API, or a command, that enumerates all the well-known (security identifier) SIDs for a Windows system?

I am trying to enumerate all the possible SIDs of a system. I could enumerate the SIDs of local users, local and global groups, and its members with calls to `NetUserEnum()` , `NetGroupEnum()`,  `NetLocalGroupEnum()`, and `NetLocalGroupGetMembers()`.

But could not find an API to query some well-known SIDs, like `Everyone S-1-1-0`, `Network S-1-5-2`, etc.

I have posted the MSDN link for the same:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems.

Retriving all the sysaccount SIDs can be done via `wmic SYSACCOUNT get name,sid`. Is there a way of getting the information via the Windows API instead?

Comment: You have the Enum: [System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]

Comment: @DanielBjörk - this and [*WELL_KNOWN_SID_TYPE*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ne-winnt-well_known_sid_type) enumeration is hardcoded in *sdk*. but in concrete os version can be more well known sids, if we use old sdk, or less, if we on old (compare sdk) version. question in run-time enumerate actual set of sids

Comment: wmic group get name,sid,domain
wmic useraccount get name,sid,domain
wmic SYSACCOUNT get name,sid,domain

How about these? The last one give both Everyone and Network SID

Comment: According to the documentation, do you want to use the OS version to determine the well-known sid list, like if `_WIN32_WINNT >=_WIN32_WINNT_WS03`(0x0502), then add S-1-3-2 etc.

Comment: @DanielBjörk thanks, and is there a way to enumerate it in  programming through api?. Sorry if this is obvious, but i am new to this.

Comment: Since you tagged your question powershell, yes you can enumerate it in powershell running the provided command in a for each loop.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT yes, but i am trying to find a api that can enumerate all the already added SID's. Else i must be hardcoding it.

Comment: @RbMm yes, it is about the run-time enumeration only.

Comment: *Retriving all the sysaccount SIDs can be done via wmic SYSACCOUNT get name,sid. Is there a way of getting the information via the Windows API instead?* maybe you could use WMI class [`Win32_SystemAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-systemaccount) in C++ as powershell